# how to increase file size in php without using php.ini file

Tags: php

I am using following code for increase uploaded file size in php but it is not working.and I want to change the file size without using php.ini file and `.htaccess`file.

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '500M');
ini_set("upload_max_filesize",'500M');
echo("<br>".ini_get('upload_max_filesize')."<br>");
```

Answer (score 5):

These values both have the changeable-mode `PHP_INI_PREDIR` meaning they can be set using php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini  but *not* `ini_set()`. This is because the post has already been received before the php script starts and `ini_set()` would have no effect anymore.

Check the [overwiew about core settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) in the PHP manual. It shows all the settings and *where* they can bet set. Also you can find an overview of the [possible change locations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

Comment: Thanks for letting know why ini_set() won't work in this case.